# Can a npm dependency require a module from its parent package

Tags: node.js, npm, require

I am building a server app as a "core" framework and (potentially) multiple specialisations, starting with "spec_a".

I would like "core" to be an npm package, and "spec_a" to be an npm package which requires "core".

While I could require spec_a's modules and pass them to core in function calls, I would prefer core to read a config file and try to require modules (which are specified in the config file) from it's parent package.  (The core shouldn't need to know the name of its parent package, as it will be different from each specialisation.)

What I am looking for is a `require_from_parent(module_name_from_config)` call.

Is there a way of making such a thing?

I was thinking of using `require('../'+module_name_from_config)`, but this is fragile and will probably break on the latest npm.

Comment: did you get this going in practice? I'm looking to do the same thing. I want my lib/dependency to require from the parents src/ dynamically.

Comment: @btd Sorry, that was over a year ago, I cannot even remember which project it was for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer here on [a nodebb blog](https://blog.nodebb.org/requiring-local-parent-modules-from-inside-a-module/).

```
var Topics = module.parent.require('./topics'),
    User = module.parent.require('./user'),
    Notifications = module.parent.require('./notifications');
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no explicit "requireFromParent" call. Whenever you call `require`, it will first look in its own node_modules folder and if the module is not found, it will traverse up the directory tree and check if its parents have the module, which should work for your purposes.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right with npm 2.x.  As far as I have read, npm 3.x can place dependencies in the same directory as the parent package, so traversing up the directory tree will not find the parent modules - hence my comment about fragile.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: npm 3 essentially automatically dedupes your modules (npm2 also had that feature, but it was not automatic). It shouldn't affect your use case, as all that it should do, is place your child's dependencies in your parent's node_modules. Since the child always falls back to the parent, it should be the same as npm2. The difference now, is that if your parent and child had the same exact dependency, only the parent will install it, and the child will take the parent's copy.